Python code which can find combination of negative numbers that exactly matches with the positive one and highlight them as well in excel sheet
suppose in “A” Column of excel there are negative numbers such as -1, -3,-6,-8 and a positive number 11 now i want python to find the combination of those negative numbers which if added together will be exactly equal to 11 like -8 and -3 and their difference with the positive no will be 0 and at the same time highlight the cell of those negative numbers as well and save the output excel file.
The above numbers are just for example

Please Assist 


**This is the code which i used but not getting the results I guess there is an issue in Logic applied **

import pandas as pd
import itertools
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

# Load the Excel file
input_file = 'input.xlsx'
output_file = 'output.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(input_file)

# Extract the numbers from column A
numbers = df['A'].tolist()

# Separate the positive number and negative numbers
positive_num = None
negative_nums = []

for num in numbers:
    if isinstance(num, (int, float)):
        if num > 0:
            positive_num = num
        elif num < 0:
            negative_nums.append(num)

# Function to find the combinations
def find_combinations(nums, target):
    for r in range(1, len(nums) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(nums, r):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                return subset
    return None

# Find the combination of negative numbers that sum to the positive number
combination = find_combinations(negative_nums, positive_num)

# Load the workbook and select the active sheet
wb = load_workbook(input_file)
ws = wb.active

# Highlight the numbers in the combination
if combination:
    fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFFF00", end_color="FFFF00", fill_type="solid")
    for cell in ws['A']:
        if cell.value in combination:
            cell.fill = fill

# Save the modified file
wb.save(output_file)
print(f"The output file has been saved as {output_file}")


I found a solution:
from itertools import combinations

def find_combinations(nums, target):
    combinations_list = []
    for i in range(len(nums) + 1):
        combinations_list.extend([list(comb) for comb in combinations(nums, i) if target + sum(comb) == 0])

    return combinations_list

def main():
    target = 11
    nums = [[-1, -3, -6, -8],
            [-12, -4, -1, -9],
            [-5, -4, -8, -2],
            [-11, -1, -3, -2],
            [-4, -6, -7, -5]
           ]
    [print(lst) for lst in nums]
    print()

    # If you only want to check one list instead of multiple you can
    # delete this for loop and make the list nums = [-1, -3, -6, -8]
    # Ooh and don't forget about | lst you need to change it to nums
    for lst in nums: #           v
        print(find_combinations(lst,target))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This is the output:
[-1, -3, -6, -8]
[-12, -4, -1, -9]
[-5, -4, -8, -2]
[-11, -1, -3, -2]
[-4, -6, -7, -5]

[[-3, -8]]
[]
[[-5, -4, -2]]
[[-11]]
[[-4, -7], [-6, -5]]


Can you just modify that portion of code which require modification in my code keeping other things same bec i need it to be dynamic that whenever i update my excel sheet numbers it automatically fetches new series and calculate the combination I know I’m asking for extra but I’m not that into code i did all with the help of chat gpt basically I’m from finance background.. and thank you for taking your timeout .. if you can do this then it would be of great help

Also if I’m simply using your code I’m not getting any output

Bro, I rewrote your find_combinations function the only thing you need to do is delete your old find_combinations function, copy my find_combinations function and paste it in your code that's all.

Hi Mathew thanks let me try I’ll update you
